# How do I connect to a Azure Compute Emulator on my local machine

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I have a WorkerRole running as a Cloud Service.  I want to debug it because when I call the service on Azure the calling application hangs.

I tried attaching the debugger to the remote service but it times out after 90 minutes of doing nothing.  So, my next step is to run the service locally with the emulator, which I am now doing.

I have the emulator running but I have no idea how to connect to this local service and what the endpoint is.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to debug your Azure cloud service (running in the cloud), you first need to make sure it is built with the Debug configuration and that the remote debugger feature is enabled, then you'll be able to attach to the role from Visual Studio as if you were running it locally.

To do the debugging locally, with the Azure Emulator, all you need to do is to run your cloud service project (F5 (if it is the default project) or right click -> Debug -> Start new instance).

You can follow these steps to enable the debugger and attach to the service (both locally and in the cloud): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Another step that I missed was connecting to my Worker Role locally on my local IP Address.  After running the local emulator my code to connect to the Cloud Service had to be updated to my loopback IP, 127.0.0.1.  The port I specified stayed the same.